# How to get an image from drawables onto canvas via interaction

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have created a canvas on android which has a circle drawn on and buttons however I want an image from the drawables to be dropped in via some sort of interaction so I thought of using a button, but I have created this screen only using the content view of the java class, thus I cannot use xml so is there any way you guys would know how I can grab the image on click in java (programatically).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can draw anything on canvas,and add events to custom class that you have designed...

take a look  http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/05/draw-bitmap-on-view.html